# How to Decide What Page Size to Use on an iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing, pdf-generation, page-size

Wikipedia says that the US and Canada use *letter* size paper and the rest of the world uses *A4* and that some countries use both. I want to create a PDF in my iPad application and am trying to figure out a clean way to determine whether to set my bounds to *letter* or *A4*. I am also looking for any common patterns used to let someone change from one size to the other.

I have already looked at [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755480/ios-4-how-do-i-simulate-an-a4-printer) to get some of the basics down with region checking.

So, my question rephrased as a question: is there any way other than checking to see what region and then assuming that US/Canada are *letter* to know the user's preferred default paper size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking the user locale and decide based on that? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios).

Comment: That's basically the strategy I have come up with and then added a switch to change it in the settings pane. I just don't like it because it feels clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You could let them select their own paper size.

Comment: I can. I just wanted the app to be smart about it and make a guess that would be the correct one 90% of the time.